# subdomain to act as a parameter in .htaccess and php not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I know this topic has been discussed many times in this forum, but I am totally lost with .htaccess and will appreciate any help with this query

I have 2 subdomains on a site

aaa.sitename.com
bbb.sitename.com

there are no subfolders for the subdomains, and all query land into the default folder of the site

my intentions is to pass 2 values to the index.php as in

aaa.sitename.com/clubvalue  ==>   index.php?md=aaa&club=clubvalue

or

bbb.sitename.com/clubvalue  ==>   index.php?md=bbb&club=8868

they work fine when called as below (i can extract md and club details with a $_GET)

[www.sitename.com/index.php?md=aaa&club=2323](http://www.sitename.com/index.php?md=aaa&club=2323)

aaa.sitename.com/index.php?md=aaa&club=2323

bbb.sitename.com/index.php?md=bbb&club=2323

but when called as

aaa.sitename.com/2323

its showing **404 page not found error**

if called as aaa.sitename.com

both md and club returns a blank value

my .htaccess file is as follows..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Also do not rewrite real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#For everything else, index.php should fetch the proper content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{1,2})\.domain\.xx$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?club=%1&md=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Your RewriteCond demands that the subdomain part consists of one or two letters only. With the examples you have given, could that be the problem here already?

Answer (score 0):

I would send anything and everything to the index.php page and explode GET variables over there.

If you have a copy of WordPress then use it's .htaccess or download WordPress and use it's .htaccess for the same.